# Can you use Rockite instead of Gypcrete?

Tags: subfloor

Can you used Rockite instead of gypcrete to repair a subfloor in a multi-family apartment repair?

Comment: Please revise to add more information about your situation. The question is quite broad as it is, and therefore off-topic. The [product page](http://www.rockitecement.com/) says you can repair floors, so there's no further answer required.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve never used Rockite, but I’ve used Gypcrete many times.

Gypcrete is used for large areas and is “soupy” when installed. It hardens and is not intended to be walked on without a floor covering, like carpet, vinyl tile, etc.

Rockite appears to be for smaller projects and can be manipulated to conform to any shape. Here’s a website that explains it better: http://www.rockitecement.com/

BTW, make sure your base is solid with no voids or the Gypcrete could flow through any small opening/crack/etc. Rockite doesn’t seem to have that issue.